# In Rails while using the Devise gem how to set custom subject line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Im trying to turn the reset password mail into a create account mail if the user is not confirmed. If the user is confirmed it will send the normal reset password link. Now the only problem I have is the subject line. I tried to change it like this :

```
 def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    if record.confirmed?
        @confirm = true        
    else
        @confirm = false
        headers = { 
               :subject => "Welcome to SLMUN"
        }
    end     
  super
 end
```

But it didn't work. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to assign the subject through `opts[:subject]` like this :

```
def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    opts[:subject] = 'Welcome to SLMUN'  
    super
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `rails g devise views` you can see all of the mailers that are created behind-the-scenes by Devise. You should be able to find the mailer you're after in its directory and directly edit it there.

EDIT:

You will need to use the `headers` method to set the headers, not a variable.

See the [Rails Guides on the subject](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Comment: Yes I put this in a generated mailer. See the @custom variable? I used it to customize the mail's content. It works. Thats means this function works. But the header doesn't work.

Comment: Should that headers be a regular variable and not a method? It's been a while since I've worked with `ActionMailer`.

Comment: Have updated my answer. It is a method you need called `headers`, not a variable as you're setting.

Comment: I used `mail(subject: 'Welcome to SLMUN')` that also doesn't work